# How to write JSONata query to remove duplicate values from some tags in json and to get unique value of each object using jsaonata

Tags: jsonata

**Source of json entry** is like below
I want to get unique value from keys Type* and Category* for each "Proudcts" object

```
{
    "data" : {
        "Products" : [
        {
            "Type" : "Apple",
            "Type_2" : "Lemon",
            "Type_3" : "Apple",
            "Category" : "Pear",
            "Category_2" : "Peanut"
            "Category_3" : "Lemon",
            "Area" : "Lot1",
            "Key" : "Section1"          
        },
        {
            "Type" : "Pear",
            "Type_2" : "Grape",
            "Type_3" : "Lemon",
            "Category" : "Lemon",
            "Category_2" : "Pear"
            "Category_3" : "Walnut",
            "Area" : "Lot2",
            "Key" : "Section2"
        }
        ]
    }       
}
```

**Expected results** are

```
{
    "Items" : [
    {
        "Collection" : "Apple",
        "Area" : "Lot1",
        "Key" : "Section1"
    },
    {
        "Collection" : "Lemon",
        "Area" : "Lot1",
        "Key" : "Section1"
    },
    {
        "Collection" : "Pear",
        "Area" : "Lot1",
        "Key" : "Section1"
    },
    {
        "Collection" : "Peanut",
        "Area" : "Lot1",
        "Key" : "Section1"
    },
    {
        "Collection" : "Pear",
        "Area" : "Lot2",
        "Key" : "Section2"
    },
    {
        "Collection" : "Grape",
        "Area" : "Lot2",
        "Key" : "Section2"
    },
    {
        "Collection" : "Lemon",
        "Area" : "Lot2",
        "Key" : "Section2"
    },
    {
        "Collection" : "Apple",
        "Area" : "Lot2",
        "Key" : "Walnut"
    }
    ]
}
```

Unique value from Type* and Category* of each source object is shown for value of Collection tag.
Can anyone help me to write jsonata to get expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need to iterate over all possible values of Type and Category properties. To achieve that, you can use a combination of `$keys` and `$lookup` functions with a filtering operation in-between, like this:

```
{
  "Items": data.Products.(
    $product := $;
    $typeAndCategoryKeys := $keys($product)[$contains($, "Category") or $contains($, "Type")];
    $typeAndCategoryValues := $typeAndCategoryKeys.($lookup($product, $)) ~> $distinct;

    $typeAndCategoryValues.{
      "Collection": $,
      "Area": $product.Area,
      "Key": $product.Key
    }
  )
}
```

Check it out on the [JSONata Playground](https://www.stedi.com/jsonata/playground?statev2=eJyFklFLwzAQx79KCHlYIRTX6ctEofggog8DRR%2FaIqENUtYlIU3BYedn97I0XTfb7Sl397%2Fkf%2FxySYJr2eicY4r5t9K8rkspIGHtVTuH8ycVCKW4YIaleIn2qS2stCya3NS2mLgi8qrreNsqbtUUx0pVENJT9TNy%2BgvfSDGmL6bvPzDDv6Teuo4VZ3qiwZtAi2jMVNNiepJYc9ap0sxPxGfeTfDKcwPkQPfyjl7AMjL0kMqjZmqU2plZj6mc6xhgmSTXGX2w6j%2B5IyrRBSrRgIoLMntAvDus2JPhm%2F062V0L%2FX6FM3eBKFdAyztEbruaARyxKPzAYFvv9TUEM38jSEguhWGlgBo9ghQgqdGJ6v4nyCY83lnVcOcy4h7OSCXlulG9O0UkCNDvPSJFWZtS5AYePvd02G8LTCqryhG0XAg9KB6%2FtwltYaB3P9DLNhc9%2F8CBl23ULtprnFF8g7M%2FQisqcQ%3D%3D)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works as expected.